# Can't sign in to Atlassian Bitbucket from brave browser

Tags: browser

When I try to login to my Bitbucket in brave browser, Atlassian displays the error below:

'You may run into this issue when you use specific browsers or add-ons that hide the referer header for id.atlassian.com and other Atlassian sites. Check for these and then try logging in again.'

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get around it is to turn the Brave shield off while you're on the login page.

The easiest way to start over is to open an incognito window in Brave, and then go back to the Bitbucket home page and click Log In.

Once it brings you to the login page, that has a URL like `https://id.atlassian.com/login?...` **turn the Brave Shield off.**

Once the Brave shield is turned off, you can put in your username and password. It will log you into your Bitbucket home page where you can see your repos.

Comment: That did not work, looks like I have to use a different browser just to use Bitbucket..

Comment: @Coder111 I was able to get it to work. I had the same issue until taking off the shield. Can you ensure you did all of the steps correctly?

Comment: Tried again, it worked! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Coder111 glad it worked. I was just about to make a recording of what I did.